# elasticsearch not_analyzed doesn't work

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, mapping

Why elastic search not_analyzed doesn't work I am trying to solve

The mapping is visible here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGj7A.png

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/gb/_analyze?field=tag?pretty' -d 'Black-cats'
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/gb/_analyze?field=tweet?pretty' -d 'Black-cats' 
the results are the same
{
    "tokens": [{
        "token": "black",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 5,
        "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position": 1
    }, {
        "token": "cats",
        "start_offset": 6,
        "end_offset": 10,
        "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position": 2
    }]
}
```

Comment: Please, write clearly

Comment: Do you have one of those fields set to not_analyzed via the mappings?  And so one of those results is unexpected?  Can you please provide a relevant snippet from the mapping?

Comment: sorry my english is poor. I've got the answer. One of my nodes has different Chinese analyzer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your URL wrong, i.e. you have two `?` characters, the one before `pretty` should be an ampersand `&`, try this one

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/gb/_analyze?field=tag&pretty' -d 'Black-cats'
                                                       ^
                                                       |
                                          this should be a &, not a ?
```